# Convert Type to List

Tags: c#

Boa tarde,

Estou a desenvolver um projeto em C# e surgiu-me erro agora ado qual não estou a cosneguir resolver.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ITCore.FlowCredit.Business.Entities.ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

```
 public override List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias> GetTodosDiasAmortizacaoCredito(int? id_TipoDia, String id_Produto)
{
        List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias> ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasObj = new List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias>();

        try
        {
            ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasObj = **ProdutoAmortizacaoDiasUtils.GetTodosProdutoAmortizacaoDias(id_TipoDia, id_Produto);**
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CoreLog.LogError(ex);
            throw new CoreException(ex.Message);
        }
        return ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasObj;
    }
```

Como converto aqui?

```
  #region Gets

    public static ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch GetTodosProdutoAmortizacaoDias(int? id_TipoDia, String id_Produto)
    {
        ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch res = new ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch();
        List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias> ProdutoAmortizacaoDiasList = new List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias>().ToList();

        using (TaxasProdutoExtensaoPrazoDBDataContext ctx = new TaxasProdutoExtensaoPrazoDBDataContext())
        {
            var results = ctx.usp_DiaAmortizacaoCredito_GetDiaAmortizacaoCredito(id_TipoDia, id_Produto);
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                var obj = new ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias();
                obj.Id = (int)result.id;
                obj.Dia = (int)result.dia;
                obj.DiaInicio = (DateTime)result.data_Inicio;
                obj.DiaFim = (DateTime)result.data_Fim;
                ProdutoAmortizacaoDiasList.Add(obj);
            }
        }
        res.result = ProdutoAmortizacaoDiasList;
        res.ReturnValue = 1;//tens de buscar isto à bd
        res.NumberRecords = ProdutoAmortizacaoDiasList.Count; //buscares à bd, ou assim, depende como queres fazer
        return res;
    }
```

Obrigado,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está tentando fazer uma variável do tipo **`List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias>`** receber o valor de **outro tipo**, `ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch`, no caso.

Veja

```
var ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasObj = new List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias>();
```

Aqui é instanciado uma lista de **`ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias`**.

Na linha abaixo, dentro do `try`, tem o seguinte

```
ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasObj = ProdutoAmortizacaoDiasUtils.GetTodosProdutoAmortizacaoDias(id_TipoDia, id_Produto);
```

Ou seja. Pegue o retorno do método `GetTodosProdutoAmortizacaoDias` na classe `ProdutoAmortizacaoDiasUtils` e coloque na variável `ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias`.

Porém, o retorno do método `GetTodosProdutoAmortizacaoDias` **não é uma lista de `ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias`** e sim uma instância de `ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch`.

Veja a assinatura do método:

```
public static ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch GetTodosProdutoAmortizacaoDias(/*params*/)
```

---

### Solução

O tipo **`ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch`** tem uma propriedade `result` e, aparentemente, é nela que fica a lista que você precisa.

Então, faça o seguinte:

```
try
{
    ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasObj = ProdutoAmortizacaoDiasUtils.GetTodosProdutoAmortizacaoDias(id_TipoDia, id_Produto).result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    CoreLog.LogError(ex);
    throw new CoreException(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o retorno do seu primeiro método deveria ser

```
return ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasObj.result;
```

Pelo menos faria mais sentido já que esta propriedade é um `List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias>`

Comment: Retiraram os comentários que tinham aqui?